# Add a folder from a repository as a submodule in another repository

Tags: git, github

i have a repository having two folder client and server i want to add a folder of another repository as a submodule in server folder.

I have tried running this command
`git submodule add -b main git@github.com:bhupender/utils.git core`

but it is adding the entire utils repo in core folder instead what i want is to add only utils/helper as a submodule

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit-submodules%5D+subfolder

Comment: "Git does not support partial checkouts, so the submodule must point to a complete repository." "What you want to do is not feasible because you cannot clone a part of a repository." "I'm afraid the URL for submodules always just points to the repository - you can't specify that you only want a subfolder of a repository, in the same way that git doesn't support "narrow clones" in general."